# Email description parsing through to SendLog

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

To pass the Email Name to the SendLog you need to add an AMPScript with "emailname_" system string to obtain that field. Is there a similar system string to pass the Email Description (the field in Email Properties)?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn’t.  Here’s the full list of all personalization strings associated with Email Data in Marketing Cloud:

- %%xtmonth%%
  Full name of the month in which the email is sent
- %%xtmonthnumeric%%
  Current month as a number
- %%xtday%%
  Current date of the month when the email was sent (for example, 22)
- %%xtdayofweek%%
  Current day of the week when the email was sent (for example, Thursday)
- %%xtyear%%
  Current year when the email was sent
- %%xtshortdate%%
  Current date when the email was sent in short format. For example, 12/13/2010
- %%xtlongdate%%
  Current date when the email was sent in long format. For example, Monday, December 13, 2010
- %%linkname%%
  Descriptive name of a hyperlink, known as the link alias. This string populates with the value of the link's alias or the complete URL if no alias is specified at the link level. This personalization string is only available in use with the web analytics connector. This string allows a web analytic programs to identify web activity that initiated from an individual link within the email. Link alias values generated via personalization strings, AMPscript, or SSJS don’t reflect in the %%linkname%% value.
- %%emailname_%%
  Internal name of the email
- %%_messagecontext%%
  Context in which the customer views the email. Resolves to these values:

SEND - Display the rendered final message for sending to subscriber

PREVIEW - Display the send preview options available within editor

VAWP - Display content

VIEWSENT - Display the non-subscriber link to preview content

FTAF - Display the rendered Forward To a Friend message

LANDINGPAGE - Display a landing page or microsite

VALIDATION - Display information corresponding to the validate option in Marketing Cloud

LINKRESOLUTION - Display resolved dynamic script at click time

SMS - Display SMS message content

SOCIAL - Display Social Forward content

SITE - Display CloudPages content

- %%_MessageTypePreference%%
  Resolves to Text or HTML according to the subscriber's email type preference
- %%_replycontent%%
  The body of the email you sent. This personalization string is used in triggered sends to place the body of an email into a reply email
- %%_IsTestSend%%
  Resolves to True if the email job is marked as a Test Send.
- %%jobid%%
  Email send ID (the unique identifier associated with the send of the email, for tracking data purposes)
- %%_PreHeader%%
  Any content with the assigned value for the Preheader attribute of the email message
- %%Email_Preheader%%
  Populates the preheader in an email from the brand tags.
- %%double_opt_in_url%%
  Inserts the double opt-in link in an email.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&language=en_US

That said, the only way to pass the email description to the SendLog would be to create an AMPscript variable in each email and fill out the description in each email manually and have that variable saved in the SendLog, eg.

```
%%[
set @emailDescription = "Welcome email for new customers"
]%%
```

And in the SendLog, create a new `emailDescription` field where the value form the AMPscript variable will be saved.